# How to playback Rosbag pointcloud2 files

Tags: rosbag, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm currently trying to playback a rosbag file made with pointcloud2, and I can do it with the rviz software, but for my purposes, I need to be able to go back and forth in the video (like you would in a media player with a regular video) , not just in one direction. Is there any way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234627/how-to-playback-rosbag-pointcloud2-files/) by [cheses100](https://answers.ros.org/users/26906/cheses100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can use rqt. Please check http://wiki.ros.org/rqt

---

Originally posted by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) with karma: 18 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A G](https://answers.ros.org/users/26851/a-g/) on 2016-05-18**:
please check http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag as you may need rqt_bag_plugins as well.

**Comment by [cheses100](https://answers.ros.org/users/26906/cheses100/) on 2016-05-19**:
I tired using that but since all I have access to is camera/depth_registered/points, it only gives me the option to view it as raw and as a plot. Is there some way I could make it show me the image/video too?

**Comment by [cheses100](https://answers.ros.org/users/26906/cheses100/) on 2016-05-19**:
Alright so I got it working. In case anyone else has this same issue what I had to do was first run the convert_pointcloud_to_image command and then load /camera/depth/cloud_image into rqt_bag